# Google Authentication error "500. That’s an error"

Tags: google-oauth, google-api-java-client

Since about 1 week ago I'm getting consistently `500. That’s an error` from accounts.google.com side when trying to authenticate with Google.

The first request to

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=openid%20email%20https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive%20https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds%20https://docs.google.com/feeds&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https://<XXXXXX>/&state=<XXXX>2&client_id=<MY_CLIENT_NUMBER>.apps.googleusercontent.com&hd=
```

returns 200, but then the second request to

```
https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth?hd&client_id=<app_id>.apps.googleusercontent.com&as=-XXXXXX&nosignup=1&destination=https://<my_app_uri>&approval_state=<somewhatrandomstate>&xsrfsig=<signature>
```

almost always fails with 500.

I'm using Java Google API client version 1.22.0 and my application is deployed on AWS (region `eu-central-1`). I'm currently signed in to multiple google accounts, so Account Chooser is triggered.

Any ideas what could be the problem? This auth flow worked fine for long time before then.

Comment: This may help https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/oauth2-dev/MHH8LqxBSXI   500 errors to the auth server are hard to diagnose.

Comment: where did you find this endpoint?  https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth

Comment: I've already seen that, but it seems to be unrelated especially because those posts are more than 5 years old. Google recently rolled out new Account Chooser which might be related (see https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7338427?)

Comment: @DalmTo: acccounts.google.com/sigin/oauth is already something on Google side that's not under my control (it's requested from script loaded from ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/o/2908553608-xsrfstatemanager.js:2)

Comment: I notice your first request has "hd=" with no value, and the request to /signin/oauth has a valueless "hd" parameter. Is that a copy-paste error on SO or the real requests you're sending?

Comment: @Nick it's the real request and when I remove it and call the last endpoint without it then I'm correctly redirect back with proper state and all other required parameters, so it's seems to be cause of this problem.

Comment: If you are using the java client library i think you should include your code

Comment: @DalmTo: The problem was that I was including `hd` parameter, but setting it's value to empty string. This was handled gracefully earlier on until 1-2 weeks ago. After removing this parameter/setting it to meaningful value the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a very slight change of behavior on Google side. Mainly handling `hd` parameter. Before this change `hd` parameter was accepted even empty, but now when it's empty it usually ends up with status code `500`.